# Ошибка при установке pyautogui

Tags: python-3.x, linux

При установке pyautogui выводится ошибка

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/kreuk/programming/python/dwmlMusic/env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j0513z0z/pyautogui/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j0513z0z/pyautogui/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-nbksuruq
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j0513z0z/pyautogui/
  Complete output (6 lines):
  usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: setup.py --help-commands
     or: setup.py cmd --help
  
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyautogui
```

scrot, python3-tk и python3-dev я установил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо уважаемому [Sergey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213498/sergey) за ответ.
Но `wheel` у меня уже был установлен. А проблема решилась всего лишь переустановкой `wheel`

Answer (score 1):

> При установке pyautogui выводится ошибка

Ну да, пишет явно:

```
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
```

Нет такой программы...Есть (у меня) вот такая: */usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py*.

Как победить эту проблему, описано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci

Надо просто поставить два модуля:

```
pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```